# BitmapData - triangular transformation

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

Hey, this is really annoying me.

I have a big code, but essentially, this part comes to transformation of a **BitmapData** to triangle points, using affine transformation.

Also - I know that **BitmapData** is rectangular - the last, fourth point of the transformation is just the first one reflected over the axis defined by the other two points.

A small thing so you can see which point is which one:

```
1........2
. / / / /|
./ / / /
. / / /  |
./ / /
. / /    |
./ /
. /      |
./
3 - - - -4 - 4th point reflected
```

This whole process would come to scaling, rotating and skewing the **BitmapData** based on the angles between the points...

But somehow my code still does not work.

Looking at a similar thing in PaperVision 3D - still didn't work?

Can anybody please post a code, or a link to code for this?

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you're asking. However I can point you to an excellent description of the transform matrix, which is I think what you're interested in: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this, might help:

[triangles and uvs in flash](http://edvardtoth.com/flashfun/basic-bitmap-distortion-using-triangles-and-uvs-source/)